# How to change a array of objects to array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have schema like this,

```
const userSchema = new Schema({ 
  firstName: { type: String, required: true }, 
  documents: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Documents", required: true }], 
  status: { type: Boolean, default: true }, 
  isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false } ,
});
```

I have my document like this...

```
{
        user: {
            documents: [
               {id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"), name: "abc"},
               {id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"), name: "xyz"}
            ]
    }
}
```

I need to convert it like this and update the document

```
{
    user: {
        documents: [
          ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
          ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `documents` array and return `id` only from in,

**Update using `updateMany()` with [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2**

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [{
    $set: {
      documents: {
        $map: {
          input: "$documents",
          in: "$$this.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u3yTOfIO3Qj)

Comment: Good one, I missed that aggreagation update operators.

Comment: tried it, didn't work, I need to update the existing data in the collection.

Comment: have you tried updateMany() option, what is the error, and make sure you have mongodb 4.2 or greater version

Comment: Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1

Comment: please confirm your mongodb version? and where you executing this query?

Comment: mongo v4.2.7
executing query on the shell

Comment: sometime shell version is lower than mongodb, check both's version should be above 4.2.

Comment: this is the schema i need to update from the example sorry for the mistake in the question, running same version in mongodb 4.2...
const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    documents: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Documents", required: true }],
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

Comment: @TanjirAntu have you resolved your problem?

Comment: @turivishal Yes, I have run the updates through a node script, fetched all users and hit an endpoint with userId using loop. But could not update it through query